# Hadoop> WordCount sort by value

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop

I am working on sorting WordCount example by frequency of words.
I looked for some posts and found out that I can not do sorting by value in a MapReduce.
So I decided to make two map reduce jobs separately. Thus the first one is original wordcount and the second one reads the output from the first MapReduce and sorting words by their frequency.

The input file the second MapReduce uses is like the following (which is the output of the first MapReduce)

> 1    apple
>
> 2    ball
>
> 1    cartoon
>
> 4    day

And here is the code for the second mapreduce code.
I made a Pair class which I think unnecessary here and used it as keys.

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;


import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

//Sorting by valuel
public class Sorting
{
//Using custom writable
public static class Pair implements WritableComparable<Pair>
{
    private Text t;
    private IntWritable i;
    
    public void set(Text t, IntWritable i)
    {
        this.t = t;
        this.i = i;
    }
    
    public Text getFirst() { return t; }
    public IntWritable getSecond() { return i; }
    
    
    public Pair()
    {
        set(new Text(), new IntWritable());
    }
    
    public Pair(Text t, IntWritable i)
    {
        set(t, i);
    }
    
    public int compareTo(Pair p)
    {
        int cmp = t.compareTo(p.t);
        if(cmp != 0)
        {
            return cmp;
        }
        return i.compareTo(p.i);
    }
    
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException
    {
        t.write(out);
        i.write(out);
    }
    
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException
    {
        t.readFields(in);
        i.readFields(in);
    }   
}

//public class RecordReader<IntWritable, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext contxt)

public static class SortingMapper extends Mapper<IntWritable, Text, Pair, NullWritable> 
{
    String[] output1 = null;
    //private Text word = new Text();
    
    @Override
    public void map(IntWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        output1 = value.toString().split(" ");
        
        Text word = new Text(output1[0]);
        IntWritable freq = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(output1[1]));
        
        context.write(new Pair(word, freq), NullWritable.get());
    }
            //.write() is the method inherited from interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext        
}



public static class FirstPartitioner extends Partitioner<Pair, NullWritable>
{
    @Override
    public int getPartition(Pair p, NullWritable n, int numPartitions)
    {
        System.out.println("Partitioner");
        String word = p.getFirst().toString();
        
        char first = word.charAt(0);
        char middle = 'n';
        
        if(middle < first)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else 
            return 1 % numPartitions; //why does % need???
    }
}

public static class KeyComparator extends WritableComparator
{   
    
    protected KeyComparator()
    {
        super(Pair.class, true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2)
    {
        System.out.println("keyComparator");
        Pair v1 = (Pair) w1;
        Pair v2 = (Pair) w2;
        
        /*
         * since we already count word in the first MR we only need to sort the list by frequency
         * so no need to compare Text again
        int cmp = Pair.compare(v1.getFirst(), v2.getFirst());
        if(cmp != 0) {  return cmp; }
        */ 
        
        return -1 * v1.compareTo(v2);
        //possible error: it compares Text first and then compare IntWritable 
    }
}

public static class GroupComparator extends WritableComparator
{
    protected GroupComparator()
    {
        super(Pair.class, true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2)
    {
        System.out.println("group Comparator");
        Pair v1 = (Pair) w1;
        Pair v2 = (Pair) w2;
        return v1.getFirst().compareTo(v2.getFirst());
        //this compareTo is under binarycomparable
    }
}

public static class SortingReducer extends Reducer<Pair, NullWritable, Pair, NullWritable>
{
    @Override
    public void reduce(Pair p, Iterable<NullWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("sortingReducer");
        context.write(p, NullWritable.get());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    
    Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();
    //String[] otherArgs2 = new GenericOptionsParser(conf1, args).getRemainingArgs();
    
    ControlledJob cJob2 = new ControlledJob(conf2);
    conf2.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", " ");
    cJob2.setJobName("Sorting");
    
    Job job2 = cJob2.getJob();
    
    job2.setJarByClass(Sorting.class);
    
    job2.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    
    job2.setMapperClass(SortingMapper.class);
    job2.setPartitionerClass(FirstPartitioner.class);
    job2.setSortComparatorClass(KeyComparator.class);
    job2.setGroupingComparatorClass(GroupComparator.class);
    job2.setReducerClass(SortingReducer.class);
    
    job2.setOutputKeyClass(Pair.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
    
    job2.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path("hdfs:///tmp/inter/part-r-00000"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[0]));
    
    job2.waitForCompletion(true);
    
}
```

}

When I execute the above code I got casting error.

```
FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to     org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
    at Sorting$SortingMapper.map(Sorting.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

I just start to learn hadoop and it is the first one I made on my own.
Please let me know how to solve this error and I would be appreciated if you give me some comments on the overall code.

Comment: Yes I read something about secondary sort but can I do this problem with just one mapreduce? I thought I can't so I tried to use chaining mapreduce.

Comment: I will take back my comments. I believe Secondary sort just sorts the values associated with each key rather that the entire keys. I mis- understood your problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing your Mapper definition to following wold get you running since you are anyways not using the Key of mapper so rest of your Logic remains the same

```
  public static class SortingMapper extends Mapper<**Text**, Text, Pair, NullWritable> 
  {
    String[] output1 = null;
//private Text word = new Text();

  @Override
public void map(**Text** key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException,        InterruptedException {
///////
  }
```

Comment: But since the input I use is in the form of (intWritable, Text) like (2, ball), I thought I had to use IntWritable as a key. I may not fully understand how mapper distinguishes keys and values in given input file. Can you explain how mapper recognizes keys and values? thank you again

Comment: it All depends on the input format you are using, in this case you are   using KeyValueTextInputFormat which extends FileInputFormat<Text,Text>
which basically tells you what key your mapper should have,  would suggest better get hold of Hadoop definitive guide its a must if you are thinking future in hadoop

Answer (score 0):

Your `SortingMapper.map()` method takes `IntWrtiable` as the key, but `KeyValueTextInputFormat` produces `Text` objects. A `Text` object can not be cast to `IntWritable`, it's why you get:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
```

Comment: Then should I make a new class to take a IntWritable as the key? Actually I found this [link](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#fileformat) is it what I need to do??